# How can I run a textarea value into JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, eval

Maybe the title needs edited to be more accurate.
I have a website where I am trying to write a coding tutorial, mostly for my own experience.
I thought a great way to teach is giving the learner a chance for a hands on experience, so I decided to try to allow the user to code in the browser, in a textarea, and more or less see the output. At first, I was using the eval function. It worked okay, for the first assignment (which was to create a string equal to "This is a string", very original, I know), but I couldn't make it flexible enough to work with much more than that, or any multi-line things.
So I guess my question is, is there a way to do this, with any libraries? I know that codecademy has done this, but...
Anyway, thank you for any answers/suggestions you have for me!

**EDIT**
I should imply, I suppose, that I need to run this code, and output whatever is returned, etc. I can handle most of that, but just want to know how to run it in the first place, or if there is a way to do so, without eval.

Comment: Here's a nice way to do Eval with JS (https://github.com/dtao/lemming.js)

Comment: @LiamB  I will check that out. Thanks!

Comment: `eval()` should work. Please post the code you tried, so we can help you understand what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a nice way to do Eval with JS (github.com/dtao/lemming.js) –  LiamB 16 mins ago

LiamB has provided me with a resource I can use, that is much more dynamic than eval, as per the question. Thanks!